# Bucle infinito al hacer scroll en listview con Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy intentando hacer con Flutter un listview que se carga a partir de una lista de datos obtenidos de una llamada a un API.

Los datos se cargan correctamente en el listview y funciona correctamente el problema es que esta llamando indefinidamente al API, entra en un bucle infinito y no para de hacer llamadas al API.

Este es el codigo:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

class NoticiasScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  NoticiasScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NoticiasScreenState createState() => _NoticiasScreenState();
}

class _NoticiasScreenState extends State<NoticiasScreen> {
  int _numeroPagina;
  bool _error;
  bool _cargando;
  final int _numNoticiasPorPagina = 10;
  List<Noticia> _listaNoticias;
  final int _umbralProximaPagina = 5;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _numeroPagina = 1;
    _error = false;
    _cargando = true;
    _listaNoticias = [];
    debugPrint('paso 0');
    obtenerNoticias();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return obtenerBody();
  }

  Widget obtenerBody() {
    if (_listaNoticias.isEmpty) {
      if (_cargando) {
        return Center(
            child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ));
      } else if (_error) {
        return Center(
            child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _cargando = true;
              _error = false;
              debugPrint('paso 3');
              obtenerNoticias();
            });
          },
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Text(
                "Upps! se ha producido un error al cargar las noticias, prueba de nuevo"),
          ),
        ));
      }
    } else {
      return ListView.builder(
          
          itemCount: _listaNoticias.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            if (index == _listaNoticias.length - _umbralProximaPagina) {
          
              debugPrint('paso 1');
              obtenerNoticias();
            }
            if (index == _listaNoticias.length) {
              if (_error) {
                debugPrint('paso error');
                return Center(
                    child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _cargando = true;
                      _error = false;
                      obtenerNoticias();
                    });
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    child: Text(
                        "Upps! se ha producido un error al cargar las noticias, prueba de nuevo"),
                  ),
                ));
              } else {
                return Center(
                    child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ));
              }
            }
            final Noticia oNoticia = _listaNoticias[index];
            return Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image(
                    image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(oNoticia.imagenCabecera),
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 160,
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 10, 25, 0),
                      title: Text(oNoticia.titulo),
                      subtitle: Text(oNoticia.cabecera)),
                ],
              ),
            );
          });
    }
    return Container();
  }

  Future<void> obtenerNoticias() async {
    try {
        final response = await http.get(
        'https:localhost:443/api/obtenerNoticias',
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Accept-encoding': 'utf-8',
        });

        List<Noticia> listadoNoticias = _parseList(json.decode(response.body));


      setState(() {
        _cargando = false;
        _numeroPagina = _numeroPagina + 1;
        _listaNoticias.addAll(listadoFotos);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('error: ' + e.toString());
      setState(() {
        _cargando = false;
        _error = true;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Al depurar la aplicacion veo en la consola que esta imprimiendo continuamente

```
debugPrint('paso 1');
```

Es un bucle infinito en el que esta entrando continuamente en "itemBuilder"y por tanto llamando continuamente al API WEB, aunque realmente solo deberia llamar una vez porque el API WEB solo me devuelve 7 elementos y el tamaño de paginacion lo tengo definido en 10, asi que solo deberia hacer una llamada al api WEB, sin embargo es un bucle infinito y no para de llamarlo.

Cualquier sugerencia sera bienvenida.

Comment: Te recomiendo este video para que veas como se pagina datos:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lxTulCxn0zM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto sucede porque el obtenerNoticias(); lo tienes dentro del itemBuilder.

ItemBuilder se llama cada que se va a renderear un objeto de la lista, por lo cual te sale un bucle infinito.

Por ejemplo, si tienes una lista de 10 objetos, tu función obtenerNoticias se va a llamar 10 veces